# ReflectionException is thrown when mapping entities in Doctrine from different databases

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, cross-database

I'm trying to use Doctrine 2 in a ZF2 application which contains two modules, each with its own database. I need to use cross-database joins so that I can associate entities from one module with entities in another. [Here's  a UML diagram](http://yuml.me/5a0c9e64.png) of the setup.

I've tried using this in my first entity (I've removed irrelevant parameters and `use` statements):

```
namespace Client\Entity;

/**
 * A website.
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users.website")
 * ...
 * @property $server
 */
class Website extends BaseEntity {

    // Other class vars ... 

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Server\Entity\Server", inversedBy="websites")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="server_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $server;
```

And this in my server entity:

```
namespace Server\Entity;

/**
 * A server.
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="servers.server")
 * ...
 * @property $websites
 */
class Server extends BaseEntity {

   // Other class vars ... 

   /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Client\Entity\Website", mappedBy="server")
    */
   protected $websites;
```

This mapping works perfectly when I create a new website entity (via a web form which uses `DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect` for the server association), but when I go to *edit* an existing website, this ReflectionException is thrown:

> Class Server\Entity\Website does not exist

The full stack trace [can be found here](http://pastebin.com/CsLD3zBi). For some reason, when the Server entity is accessed from its association with a Website entity, it thinks all of the entities exist in the `Server\Entity` namespace rather than `Client\Entity`. What do I need to do to make sure the Server entity looks in the correct module namespace?

The CLI command `orm:info` produces:

```
Found 7 mapped entities:
[OK]   Server\Entity\Server
[OK]   Client\Entity\Role
[OK]   Client\Entity\Website
[OK]   Client\Entity\User
[OK]   Client\Entity\Client
[OK]   Client\Entity\Permission
[OK]   Message\Entity\Notification
```

But `orm:validate-schema` results in:

```
[Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.
[Database] FAIL - The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file.
```

---

I have this in each one of my module's `module.config.php`:

```
'driver' => array(
    __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
        'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
        'cache' => 'array',
        'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity')
    ),
    'orm_default' => array(
        'drivers' => array(
            __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: What does `orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql` produce? Also: consider that the DBAL schema tools do introspection on a single database per time, so that may well be the issue here (known one)

Comment: @Ocramius http://pastebin.com/DrtLHqsN. Slightly different than what it was earlier when I tried - before it was trying to create the tables that exist in `users.` into the `servers.` database

Comment: @Ocramius I've also just successfully updated my schema with `orm:schema-tool:update --force`, but `validate-schema` is still returning the same database fail message

Comment: Can you also add the mapping configuration? Does `orm:generate-proxies` also throw the same exception?

Comment: Yeah, `orm:generate-proxies` shows the same error. What do you mean by mapping configuration? Where do I find that - in Module.php? I thought it might be because I was dynamically creating EntityManagers in my BaseController (with custom-defined connection arrays) which I described [here](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/issues/176). But I'm instantiating one for each module and still experiencing the same issue

Comment: Can you dump `$em->getMetadataFactory()` so that the drivers can be checked?

Comment: It's a pretty big piece of data: http://www.sendspace.com/file/cc25po

Comment: @Ocramius I've also added the driver configuration for Doctrine which is set in each one of my module's `module.config.php` file

Comment: @Ocramius - managed to fix it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix it. In my `Server\Entity\Server`, I had these getter/setter functions for adding/removing websites:

```
public function setWebsite(Website $website) 
{
   $this->websites->add($website);    
}

public function removeWebsite(Website $website)
{
   $this->websites->removeElement($website);
}
```

But you need to specify the **full namespace** as the argument:

```
public function setWebsite(\Client\Entity\Website $website) { ... }
```

Such a stupid mistake! I found the issue because I trawled through every file in the stack-trace and got to the point where it was attempting to save every method/argument in my Entity class to a proxy file (line 223ish in Doctrine/ORM/Proxy/ProxyFactory.php).

Comment: So the proxy factory was simply complaining for the wrong class name? Are you able to eventually verify if the exception message got any better with ORM master?

Comment: Because I hadn't specified a fully qualified classname, it was trying to instantiate them in the Server\Entity namespace. Perhaps there should be a way of matching a getter/setter function to an association mapping (declared through Doctrine annotation at the top of the file), so it knows what to refer to. The exception message was always the same (I don't know what you mean by ORM master). It look so long to diagnose because I was looking at the _mapping annotations_ instead of the getter/setter methods

Comment: Yes, that's because the proxy factory needs to rewrite methods: https://github.com/doctrine/common/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/ProxyGenerator.php#L759-L768 . ORM master (latest/bleeding edge) shows a custom error message for that as far as I know since I rewrote that part. Setters/getters don't need the FQCN as long as you import classes correctly with the `use` statement

Comment: Yeah, I realize that now (the `use` statements). I have version 2.3 of Doctrine Common, because it was bundled with the doctrine-module in Composer. I can see you've been busy re-writing 2.4! I'll install that now

Comment: only to test... it's not yet tagged! :)