# symfony2 doctrine onetoone get

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

i have class **miejsce**

```
namespace Miejsce\ObiektyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * Miejsce
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="mMiejsce")
 */
class Miejsce
{

...

 /**
     * @var Lokalizacja $lokalizacja
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Miejsce\LokalizacjaBundle\Entity\Lokalizacja" , mappedBy="miejsce")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $lokalizacja;

   /**
     * Get lokalizacja
     *
     * @return \Miejsce\LokalizacjaBundle\Entity\Lokalizacja
     */
    public function getLokalizacja()
    {
        return $this->lokalizacja;
    }
```

and **lokalizacja**

```
namespace Miejsce\LokalizacjaBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Miejsce\ObiektyBundle\Entity\Miejsce;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="mLokalizacja")
*
 */
class Lokalizacja {
   /**
     * @var Miejsce
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Miejsce\ObiektyBundle\Entity\Miejsce", inversedBy="lokalizacja")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $miejsce;
```

i try get object in controller :

```
$miejsce = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('MiejsceObiektyBundle:Miejsce')
            ->find(1);

 var_dump($miejsce->getLokalizacja());
```

and have null when dont have =      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
in database i have mMiejsce.id = 1 and mLokalizacja.id

so why this dont connect this elements ? 
i want get miejsce object and have filed lokalizacja - onetoone relation - id=id

what i do wrong ?

but when i push      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")

i get :

Class Miejsce\LokalizacjaBundle\Entity\Miejsce does not exist
500 Internal Server Error - ReflectionException

now i have :

ok so now i have :

```
/**
 * Miejsce
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="mMiejsce")
 */
class Miejsce
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Lokalizacja $lokalizacja
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Miejsce\LokalizacjaBundle\Entity\Lokalizacja", mappedBy="miejsce" )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="miejsce_id")
     */
    protected $lokalizacja;
```

and

```
class Lokalizacja {

    /**
     * Lokalizacja.id = Miejsce.id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    protected $id;


    /**
     * @var Miejsce
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Miejsce\ObiektyBundle\Entity\Miejsce", inversedBy="lokalizacja")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="miejsce_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $miejsce;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $miejsce_id;
```

database update work ok

```
  php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force 
Database schema updated successfully! "5" queries were executed
```

but still have :

```
 Class Miejsce\LokalizacjaBundle\Entity\Miejsce does not exist
500 Internal Server Error - ReflectionException
```

its very strange - why doctrine / symfony try find this class on diffrent bundle ? (entities is on other bundles ? maybe this is problem ?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to the [Doctrine Association Mapping Documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html), you need to specify how the relationships are mapped (via ID and objects.) Here's the example from the docs:

```
<?php
/** @Entity **/
class Customer
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Cart", mappedBy="customer")
     **/
    private $cart;

    // ...
}

/** @Entity **/
class Cart
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Customer", inversedBy="cart")
     * @JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $customer;

    // ...
}
```

For your problem, you should create a reference ID and use it for the `JoinColumn` in one of your objects. Don't forget about `inversedBy` and `mappedBy`!

```
class Miejsce
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @var Lokalizacja $lokalizacja
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Miejsce\LokalizacjaBundle\Entity\Lokalizacja", inversedBy="miejsce" )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="lokalizacja_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    protected $lokalizacja;

    // ...
}


class Lokalizacja {

    // ...

    /**
     * @var Miejsce
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Miejsce\ObiektyBundle\Entity\Miejsce",mappedBy="lokalizacja")
     */
    protected $miejsce;

    // ...
}
```

Here's what your setter/getter functions should be looking like for your mapped objects. Anywhere you try to create a new `Miejsce` inside of `Lokalizacja`, and a new `Lokalizacja` inside of `Miejsce`, you should include the full namespace

```
public function setMiejsce(Miejsce\ObiektyBundle\Entity\Miejsce $miejsce)
{
    $this->miejsce = $miejsce;
}
```

Comment: i do like you write but now have - Class Miejsce\LokalizacjaBundle\Entity\Miejsce does not exist  - why this search Miejsce\LokalizacjaBundle\Entity\Miejsce this class is on Miejsce\ObiektyBundle\Entity not LokalizacjaBundle

Comment: lokalizacja_id ? but this  relation have miejsce.id = lokalizacja.id - there is no addon row lokalizacja_id only primary to primary

Comment: Look at my edit for the code I've written for you. Notice the `lokalizacja_id`? You have to make a new variable in `Miejsce` with that name which will store the ID that is referencing to `Lokalizacja`. When using `JoinColumn` using `id` as both of the values, you are trying to map the `id` of `Miejsce` and the `id` of `Lokalizacja` to each other!

Comment: You cannot use one column as both a primary key and foreign key.

Comment: According to [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999986/reflectionexception-is-thrown-when-mapping-entities-in-doctrine-from-different-d), your getter and setter functions may not be using the full namespace when trying to define the `Miejsce` class (and vice-versa). Did you try doing `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities` to update your getter and setter functions? See my new edit for an example of the setter function you need

Comment: Yes this is it - i have error in setlers - when i remove it and auto generate - error gone - thanks