# Symfony2 + Doctrine Cross Db Relationships

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have 2 entity managers with two different connections. There are 2 different dataabases.
In short I have one database that keeps all my user credentials with FosUser and then each application gets this database to authenticate user. So one db for authentication centralized for all apps.

The problem is that I need iduser as FK in an entity of my application 
Imagine have an entity photo:

then somewhere need to do this:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Foo\UserBundle\Entity\User")
 * @Orm\JoinColumn(name="iduser", referencedColumnName=".id")
 */
 private $user;
```

When I do doctrine:schema:update I get this error:

[Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]
  The class 'Foo\UserBundle\Entity\User' was not found in the chain confi
  gured namespaces Foo\FrontEndBundle\Entity

So whats the best practice to define cross db relationships with doctrine and Symfony2?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you tried to add your database connection name in the @ORM\Table annotation? (cf : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999986/reflectionexception-is-thrown-when-mapping-entities-in-doctrine-from-different-d)

Comment: In which of two table? Photo or User table need that or both?

Comment: Both tables you are trying to join (look at the exemple in the other topic i linked in my previous comment)

Comment: No unfortunately same error pops...

Comment: Actually i think the problem is that doctrine takes your targetEntity as a class, did you tried to change `@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Foo\UserBundle\Entity\User")` by `@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\Foo\UserBundle\Entity\User")` ? It looks like doctrine tries to find the class 'Foo\UserBundle\Entity\User' in your entity's namespace

Comment: Seems doctrine internally removes the first \ and changes it again to Foo\UserBundle\Entity\User